# JSX won't render properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, concatenation, jsx

My JSX won't show up properly on my React webpage instead I get this output:

```
<div class='card'>NaNSasha<img src= NaN />Boddy Cane</div>.
```

The component:

```
import React,  {Component} from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class App extends Component{

  state = {

    string : '',
  }

  componentDidMount(){

     let posts = [

        {
          title: 'somebody toucha my spaghet',
          author: 'Karen',
          image:'https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/11/69/c7/f9/spagetti.jpg',
          location: 'Jimmy John',
          description: 'This spagetti is amazing'
        },
        {
          title: `I love food`,
          author: 'Sasha',
          image:'https://hoodline.imgix.net/uploads/story/image/610603/donuts2.jpg?auto=format',
          location: 'Boddy Cane',
          description: 'cjndwsijnjcinjw'
        }
    
  ];

      for(let i =0; i < posts.length; i ++){

        const header = `<div class='card'>${+posts[i].title}`;
        const body = posts[i].author;
        const image = `<img src= ${+posts[i].image} />`;
        const description = `${posts[i].location}</div>`;
  
        const concatThis = header + body + image + description
        this.setState({
  
          string: concatThis
        });
      };
    };
    
  render(){

    return(

      <div className='container'>
      {this.state.string}
      </div>
      
    
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

P.S I'm a student

Comment: Please read [ask], and https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. From [ask]: don't try and cram your entire question into the title, and don't make the entire body of the question your code. Add some text describing the issue, what you were expecting, etc.

Comment: Why is there + `<img src= ${+posts[i].image} />`  and header ?

Comment: I know it's not an answer, but the way you wrote your code is both hard to read and write. Use list rendering -> https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html, then ask a question about why the name pops up as `NaNSasha` rather. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for. The expression `+{}` is evaluated as `NaN`. But please use list rendering.

```
        const image = `<img src= ${+posts[i].image} />`;
                                   ^ here
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to build a string which you then store in a state and render that string after it has been updated. This is unfortunately not how you should use React.

The `state` should only be raw data, like the `posts` array with objects. It holds the content and data of the component and should not concern itself on other tasks than that. You obviously can put any type of data in a state, like a string.

```
state = {
  title: 'My food blog',
  description: 'Awesome stuff about food',
  posts: [
    {
      title: 'somebody toucha my spaghet',
      author: 'Karen',
      image:'https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/11/69/c7/f9/spagetti.jpg',
      location: 'Jimmy John',
      description: 'This spagetti is amazing'
    },
    {
      title: `I love food`,
      author: 'Sasha',
      image:'https://hoodline.imgix.net/uploads/story/image/610603/donuts2.jpg?auto=format',
      location: 'Boddy Cane',
      description: 'cjndwsijnjcinjw'
    }
  ]
}
```

The `componentDidMount` method is triggered whenever the component has been placed on the page and is now working. In there you can do things like making a change to the data or downloading data from the server. It would make sense that you would do that there because then you would first show your component, maybe show it that it is loading and then fetch data from the server. After that is done, update the state of the component with the new data and the `render` method will be called with the new data. For example (for illustration purposes):

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('urlofdatathatyouwant') // Uses AJAX to get data from anywhere you want with the Fetch API.
    .then(response => response.json()) // Tells it to read turn the response from JSON into an usable JavaScript values.
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        posts: data // Use the new data to replace the posts. This will trigger a new render.
      });
    });
}
```

The `render` method should primarely concern itself with the presentation of the data in your state. In this case it should loop over the elements in the `posts` state and create a React element for each post.

```
render() {
  const { posts } = this.state;
  return(
    <div className='container'>
      {posts.map(({ title, author, image, location, description }) => ( 
        // Loop over each post and return a card element with the data inserted.
        <div className="card">
          <span>{title}</span>
          <span>{author}</span>
          <img src={image} alt={title}/>
          <span>{location}</span>
          <span>{description}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

All put together it would look like this the example below. So the state only holds the data, `componentDidMount` is a place to do manipulation of your data after the component is on the page and `render` only outputs the HTML that you need to create with JSX.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class App extends Component{

  state = {
    posts: [
      {
        title: 'somebody toucha my spaghet',
        author: 'Karen',
        image:'https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/11/69/c7/f9/spagetti.jpg',
        location: 'Jimmy John',
        description: 'This spagetti is amazing'
      },
      {
        title: `I love food`,
        author: 'Sasha',
        image:'https://hoodline.imgix.net/uploads/story/image/610603/donuts2.jpg?auto=format',
        location: 'Boddy Cane',
        description: 'cjndwsijnjcinjw'
      }
    ]
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Do something here with the posts if you need to.
  }
    
  render() {
    const { posts } = this.state;
    return(
      <div className='container'>
        {posts.map(({ title, author, image, location, description }, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="card">
            <span>{title}</span>
            <span>{author}</span>
            <img src={image} alt={title}/>
            <span>{location}</span>
            <span>{description}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

You could even make it a bit nicer by making the card element a component as well. And since it does not have any functionality (yet) it only has to control the output.

```
const Card = ({ title, author, image, location }) => (
  <div className="card">
    <span>{title}</span>
    <span>{author}</span>
    <img src={image} alt={title}/>
    <span>{location}</span>
    <span>{description}</span>
  </div>
)
```

And then import the card into your `App` component and use it in the `render` method.

```
// App.jsx render.
render() {
  const { posts } = this.state;
  return(
    <div className='container'>
      { /* ...post taking all the properties of each post and passes them to the card element */ }
      {posts.map((post, index) => <Card key={index} {...post} />)} 
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why are you bringing in REST? That's completely out of the scope of the question.

Comment: I know. It is to illustrate a point on what you could do in the `componentDidUpdate` method regarding manipulating data. And as OP mentioned that she is a student I thought it would add context by giving a real world example. I agree that it surpasses the scope, but I will leave it up to OP to decide if it needs to be removed.